# Github Actions with Private Github Repository as Source for Terraform Modules

Tags: github, terraform, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a github organization account under which there are two repositories.

- tf-modules ( Reusable codes are written here )
- tf-consumer ( Modules are consumed here )

I'm trying to use the **"github.com/custom-organization/tf-modules/modules/ec2"** as source in the main.tf files of tf-consumer

**I'm not owner for both the repositories**, but I have admin privileges only for **tf-consumer** github repository to create any secrets just in case.

tf-consumer directory structure is as follows:

- tf-consumer/stacks/prod/main.tf
- tf-consumer/stacks/dev/main.tf

##### **Example main.tf is as follows:**

```
module "ec2_creator" {
    source = "git::https://github.com/custom-organization/tf-modules.git//modules/ec2"
    // following lines of code here
    // following lines of code here
}
```

##### **Github actions workflow is as follows:**

```
name: Terraform

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - mgmt-scp
    types: [opened, synchronize]

  push:
    branches:
      - mgmt-scp

env:
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: Terraform
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: "ACCESS-KEY"
          aws-secret-access-key: "SECRET-KEY"
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}

      - name: Install Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          terraform_version: ${{ env.TERRAFORM_VERSION }}

      - name: Terraform Init
        working-directory: ./stacks/sampler-scp
        command: |
          git config --global url."https://my-username:${MY_GH_TOKEN}@github.com/custom-organization".insteadOf "https://github.com/custom-organization"
          terraform init -input=false
        env:
          MY_GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CUSTOM_TOKEN }}

      - name: Terraform Validate
        run: terraform validate

      - name: Terraform Plan
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: terraform plan -input=false -out=tfplan

      - name: Terraform Apply
        if: github.event_name == 'push'
        run: terraform apply -input=false tfplan
```

##### **I keep getting following error**

```
│ Error: Failed to download module
│ 
│ Could not download module "ec2_creator" (main.tf:1) source code from
│ "git::https://github.com/custom-organization/tf-modules.git": error downloading
│ 'https://github.com/custom-organization/tf-modules.git': /usr/bin/git exited with
│ 128: Cloning into '.terraform/modules/ec2_creator'...
│ remote: Invalid username or password.
│ fatal: Authentication failed for
│ 'https://github.com/custom-organization/tf-modules.git/'
```

##### Things i've tried

- I've created a personal access token from Developer settings > Personal Access tokens > Tokens ( Classic ) with following permissions

  - Full Control of private repositories
  - workflow
  - read org and team memberships, read org projects
  - manage org runners and runner groups
  - read user public keys
  - read repository hooks
  - read all user profile data
  - access user email addresses ( read-only )
  - read access of projects
  - read public user gpg keys
  - read public user ssh signing keys
- I've created a secret under mgmt-scp environment a secret called as "CUSTOM_TOKEN" and provided my PAT value in it and referenced in above code.

##### **Expectation is when terraform does initialization, it should read my tf-modules repository mentioned as source**

##### What else am I missing here ? Is there a medium article of steps performed above to resolve issue should also be helpful

Comment: Have you actually tried with steps shown here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources#generic-git-repository?

Comment: Yes, infact the Personal Access Token that i've created is based off the document and couple of other readme's I research everywhere else.

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources#github

You will need to configure credentials in particular to access private repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
  - name: Terraform Init
    working-directory: ./stacks/sampler-scp
    command: |
      echo "machine github.com login x password ${MY_GH_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc
      git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf "git://github.com/"
      git config --global advice.detachedHead false
      terraform init -input=false
    env:
      MY_GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CUSTOM_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: A one line variation of this that worked for me was 
`git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.USERNAME }}:${{ secrets.PAT_GITHUB }}@github.com".insteadOf https://github.com`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue without having to implement that step. I mean, I tried but id didn't work. In my case what I did was:

Change the source to be over ssh (`git::ssh://`) as follows:

```
module "external_module" {
   source = "git::ssh://git@github.com/your-org/private-repo//modules/external"
   // ...
}
```

Then in my Github Actions workflow:

```
 - name: Add ssh key to ssh-agent
    # Supports fetching the packages. Not just the package.json git refs of legacy, but onerail scripts pulling packages.
    uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.7.0
    with:
      ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

And all the Terraform steps without changes:

```
- name: Terragrunt Format
    id: hclfmt
    run: terragrunt run-all hclfmt --terragrunt-non-interactive

  - name: Terragrunt Init
    id: init
    run: terragrunt run-all init --terragrunt-non-interactive

  - name: Terragrunt Validate
    run: terragrunt run-all validate --terragrunt-non-interactive

  # Generates an execution plan for Terragrunt
  - name: Terragrunt Plan
    id: plan
    run: terragrunt run-all plan --terragrunt-non-interactive -input=false -no-color 2>&1 | tee plan.ansi
```

Hope it works!

Comment: This will work only if there is a single repository with the terraform modules.